# how to Deserialize Date like 2013-04-09T08:08:59.320Z into my default/custom format from Json

Tags: datetime, serialization, deserialization

how to Deserialize Date like 2013-04-09T08:08:59.320Z into my default/custom format from Json
this format by default i am fetching from the server. Now i want to Deserialize in custom or Default format without using of third party tool or dll. 
how can we do it ? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the solution of the above question.

```
DateTime dates = 2013-04-09T08:08:59.302Z ;
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse(abc.modifiedDate, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);          
Console.WriteLine(d2.ToString());
```